# How to read Request header in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, collections

*hey guys , i want to read request header. below is my controller class. I used the map , now i want to check if my header contains the any of these three ids

> external id, client id , user ID+ merchant Id

how do I check these conditions , i used the contains key method, but do we any other best method.
And in last condition we have two ids , so how do we check these ids together if they are present in header or not .?*

```
@GetMapping("transactionDetails/{id}")
    TransactionResponse getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(@RequestHeader Map<String,String> headers){
        if(headers.containsKey("externalId"))
        return transactionService.getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(headers.get("externalId");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the transaction id contains header values or not, you can use the below code.

```
@GetMapping("transactionDetails/{id}")
public TransactionResponse getTransactionDetailsByExternalId(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers, @PathVariable("id") String transactionId) {
    if (headers.containsValue(transactionId))
        return transactionService.getTransactionDetailsByTransactionId(headers.get("transactionId");
}
```

Comment: no i cant use the pathVariable , data type of id is string and it is mapped with string "specificID".

Comment: You must have to use the path variable and you can take any data type in the path variable.
I have updated my answer with the string data type.

Comment: i studied this topic from here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers and other website aswell but nowehre i find that they are using the path variable with request header .

Comment: You are accepting the id in your request URL. That is the reason you have to use PathVariable in your controller method. Did you try it out?

Comment: yes i did , earlier before mentioning you . it was working fine.